# PHP regex pattern match recursive

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have this in a function which is supposed to replace any sequence of parentheses with what is enclosed in it like `(abc)` becomes `abc` any where it appears even recursively because parens can be nested.

```
$return =   preg_replace_callback(
    '|(\((.+)\))+|',
    function ($matches) {
        return $matches[2];
    },
    $s
);
```

when the above regex is fed this string `"a(bcdefghijkl(mno)p)q"` as input it returns `"ap)onm(lkjihgfedcbq"`. This shows the regex is matched once. What can I do to make it continue to match even inside already made matches and produce this `abcdefghijklmnopq'"

Comment: `/\((?:[^\(\)]*+|(?0))*\)/` this

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix the parens can appear any where in the subject string not just at the beginning of the sting

Comment: And?  this is not dependent on that.

Comment: see https://regex101.com/r/NsQSla/2

Comment: the use of `[^` is meaning not,  and is not the same as `^[` which means start of string.

Comment: Oh got it thanks. Also thanks for regex101 introduction

Comment: so you are removing the `()` right? why not just `str_replace(['(',')'], '', $str );`

Comment: He needs to omit matching parentheses not unbalanced ones like in `(ab(c)))` @ArtisticPhoenix

Comment: yes right @vevo is right I need to remove matching parens

Comment: So, um, how do you know if `(1)2)` should return `12)` or `1)2` ??

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski It is garanteed that a openning paren will also a closing bracket.

Answer (score 2):

To match balanced parenthetical substrings you may use a well-known [`\((?:[^()]++|(?R))*\)`](https://regex101.com/r/4as8mG/1) pattern (described in [**Matching Balanced Constructs**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html#balanced)), inside a [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) method, where the match value can be further manipulated (just remove all `(` and `)` symbols from the match that is easy to do even without a regex:

```
$re = '/\((?:[^()]++|(?R))*\)/';
$str = 'a(bcdefghijkl(mno)p)q((('; // Added three ( at the end
$result = preg_replace_callback($re, function($m) {
    return str_replace(array('(',')'), '', $m[0]);
}, $str);
echo $result; // => abcdefghijklmnopq(((
```

See the [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/onAFey)

To get overlapping matches, you need to use a known technique, capturing inside a positive lookahead, but you won't be able to perform two operations at once (replacing and matching), you can run matching first, and then replace:

```
$re = '/(?=(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\)))/';
$str = 'a(bcdefghijkl(mno)p)q(((';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $m);
print_r($m[1]);
// => Array ( [0] => (bcdefghijkl(mno)p)  [1] => (mno) )
```

See the [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/R5C9Tx).

Comment: your pattern is close. But doesn't match inside matches like fed with `a(bcdefghijkl(mno)p)q` it outputs `bcdefghijkl(mno)p` with a copy paste of your code showing that `(mno)` is never matched.

Comment: @CholthiPaulTtiopic: Look, [I copy/pasted your input string into my code and obtained `abcdefghijklmnopq`](http://ideone.com/Mu8szk).

Comment: Ok my bad. I run wrong pattern.One more thing.How to get matches resulting from recursion.

Comment: @CholthiPaulTtiopic: No idea what you mean by *matches resulting from recursion*. The only match in `a(bcdefghijkl(mno)p)q(((` is `(bcdefghijkl(mno)p)`, and it is in `$m[0]`. Just add it to an array that you may pass with `use (&$arr)` to the anonymous method. See http://ideone.com/UdxbWy.

Comment: What I really originally wanted to do was to match anything in a balanced parentheses like `a(bcdefghijkl(mno)p)q(((` should give me `(bcdefghijkl(mno)p)` and `(mno)` as matches [https://regex101.com/r/NsQSla/3](https://regex101.com/r/NsQSla/3).

Comment: But I understand something like this might not be trivial to achieve with regex because it looks like irregular langauge.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one,

```
  preg_match('/\((?:[^\(\)]*+|(?0))*\)/', $str )
```

https://regex101.com/r/NsQSla/1

It will match everything inside of the `(` `)` as long as they are matched pairs.

Example

```
(abc) (abc (abc))
```

will have the following matches

```
Match 1
   Full match   0-5 `(abc)`
Match 2
   Full match   6-17    `(abc (abc))`
```

Comment: please tell me how this does not answer the question `it appears even recursively because parens can be nested.`

Comment: Please clarify how it can answer this part *...to replace any sequence of parentheses with what is enclosed in it like (abc) becomes abc*

Comment: it solves the part they were stuck on.... the relacement can be as simple as `str_replace(['(',')'], '', $match[1])` after it's verified they are a matched pair of parenthesis.  It really depends on their use case, what is the best way to handle the match.

Comment: Then you need to add this extra step to your solution.

Comment: Can you make it match in already made matches so that Match3 = (abc)

Answer (score 1):

It is slightly unclear exactly what the postcondition of the algorithm is supposed to be. It seems to me that you are wanting to strip out matching pairs of `( )`. The assumption here is that unmatched parentheses are left alone (otherwise you just strip out all of the `(`'s and `)`'s).

So I guess this means the input string `a(bcdefghijkl(mno)p)q` becomes `abcdefghijklmnopq` but the input string `a(bcdefghijkl(mno)pq` becomes `a(bcdefghijklmnopq`. Likewise an input string `(a))` would become `a)`.

It may be possible to do this using `pcre` since it *does* provide some non-regular features but I'm doubtful about it. The language of the input strings is not regular; it's context-free. What @ArtisticPhoenix's answer does is match *complete* pairs of matched parentheses. What it does not do is match all nested pairs. This nested matching is inherently non-regular in my humble understanding of language theory.

I suggest writing a parser to strip out the matching pairs of parentheses. It gets a little wordy having to account for productions that fail to match:

```
<?php

// Parse the punctuator sub-expression (i.e. anything within ( ... ) ).
function parse_punc(array $tokens,&$iter) {
    if (!isset($tokens[$iter])) {
        return;
    }

    $inner = parse_punc_seq($tokens,$iter);
    if (!isset($tokens[$iter]) || $tokens[$iter] != ')') {
        // Leave unmatched open parentheses alone.
        $inner = "($inner";
    }

    $iter += 1;
    return $inner;
}

// Parse a sequence (inside punctuators).
function parse_punc_seq(array $tokens,&$iter) {
    if (!isset($tokens[$iter])) {
        return;
    }

    $tok = $tokens[$iter];
    if ($tok == ')') {
        return;
    }
    $iter += 1;

    if ($tok == '(') {
        $tok = parse_punc($tokens,$iter);
    }

    $tok .= parse_punc_seq($tokens,$iter);
    return $tok;
}

// Parse a sequence (outside punctuators).
function parse_seq(array $tokens,&$iter) {
    if (!isset($tokens[$iter])) {
        return;
    }

    $tok = $tokens[$iter++];
    if ($tok == '(') {
        $tok = parse_punc($tokens,$iter);
    }

    $tok .= parse_seq($tokens,$iter);
    return $tok;
}

// Wrapper for parser.
function parse(array $tokens) {
    $iter = 0;
    return strval(parse_seq($tokens,$iter));
}

// Grab input from stdin and run it through the parser.
$str = trim(stream_get_contents(STDIN));
$tokens = preg_split('/([\(\)])/',$str,-1,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
var_dump(parse($tokens));
```

I know this is a lot more code than a regex one-liner but it does solve the problem as I understand it. I'd be interested to know if anyone can solve this problem with a regular expression.